# New questions not getting pushed automatically nor show in page title

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh

I generally create my own custom URL to keep track of all new questions on tags that I am interested in. And every time a new question comes on those tags, I get an item saying "2 new questions" and the page title has "(2)" in it. This was very useful as I am getting notified easily when I am browsing in other tabs. But now, for the past 2 days, i am not able to see those title changes and push activities. I checked this in different browsers too. Why does this happen? Has SO removed that feature?

This is my custom URL (that I have bookmarked): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+django+jquery+django-models+list+tuples?sort=newest&pagesize=30

This is not working for single tags also like Python page? Why is this feature removed? Or is this a browser issue in Firefox?

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with the WebSocket server at the moment.

Comment: Looks like it's back. Refresh (one last time) your page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our web-sockets server(s) died. I'm still investigating "why", but: they're back now.

Comment: Why the `(s)` ? Is that handled by a provider ?

Comment: @dystroy no, but we have multiple nodes that are capable of servicing web-socket connections, sat behind a load-balancer. Simply: whatever happened, it happened to all of them. So logically to you *as an external user*, there's just `sockets.ny.stackexchange.com`, but behind the scenes there's multiple end-points for that. Usual stuff, really.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Great it's workig now...